# Drop Down Wordpress Nav not working on Firefox

Tags: css, wordpress, firefox, drop-down-menu, themes

I've altered the CSS of the NAV on this website and now it only functions in Chrome but not Firefox. Drop Downs exist on 'Menus' & 'Catering'. It was developed in WordPress and I assume I am missing something when it comes to the coding in WordPress.

Any ideas?

http://sbserver.wwwsd3.a2hosting.com/devo_williams_freshcafe/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you reload your page and hover over the navigation item as it loads, you'll notice that the submenu actually is working properly - it appears, but is subsequently hidden as the `#main-content` element animates in.

I'm not sure as to why this is happening, since your `z-index:999999` on the submenu should certainly override the `z-index:999` of `#main-content`. (I'm fairly certain the maximum value for `z-index` is a lot higher than that.) For some reason though, 999999 is being treated the same as 999, and the main wrapper is appearing over top of the submenus.

Fixing it requires only slightly decreasing the `z-index` on `#main-content`. For example, using:

```
#wrapper.boxed #main-content {
    z-index:998;
}
```

This worked for me (tested in Firefox 20), and the submenu appears above the main wrapper. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions, though I'm frankly a bit puzzled by this as well.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. If this solved your problem, don't forget to click the checkmark next to this answer to indicate it as the accepted answer.